# play framework "could not insert" exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, playframework, crud

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.
While using plays framework CRUD module to insert information into DB (mySql)
(I am using the default module insertion mechanism as shown at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/crud)
I receive the following exception

> PersistenceException occured :
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
>   [models.Mail]

In {module:crud}/app/controllers/CRUD.java (around line 152)

```
             } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
                 render("CRUD/blank.html", type, object);
             }

          } 

  Here -> object._save(); 
          flash.success(play.i18n.Messages.get("crud.created", type.modelName)); 
         if (params.get("_save") != null) { 
             redirect(request.controller + ".list"); 
          } 
          if (params.get("_saveAndAddAnother") != null) { 

         redirect(req

uest.controller + ".blank");
```

here is my mail entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Mail extends Model {


   public String title;

   public Date sentAt;
   @OneToMany
   public Set<User> sentTO;
   @OneToMany
   public Set<User> sentBCC;


    public String content;

    @ManyToOne
    public User author;

    public Mail(User author, ... ){

      //more code here
    }

}
```

controller

```
package controllers;

/**
 *
 * @author mike
 */
public class Mails extends CRUD{

}
```

[full stack]

> Execution exception (In {module:crud}/app/controllers/CRUD.java around
>   line 152) PersistenceException occured :
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
>   [models.Mail]
>
> play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
>   [models.Mail]     at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)     at
>   Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
>   [models.Mail]     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
>     at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:25)   at
>   controllers.CRUD.create(CRUD.java:152)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
>     at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)    ... 1 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not
>   insert: [models.Mail]     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2345)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2852)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)   at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
>     ... 8 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'isAdmin' doesn't
>   have a default value  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2407)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2325)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
>     ... 23 more

any ideas?

Comment: Have you extended your Controller with CRUD controller given by Play

Comment: can you copy the whole stacktrace of the error?

Comment: added controller and full stack, as you can see it extends CRUD class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the actual cause

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'isAdmin' doesn't have a default value
```

Looks like you're trying to save into a row without setting the isAdmin property (which is also not defined in your model, but might be in your actual database?).

Comment: you are correct, it was the old model class, I've deleted 'IsAdmin' field from class but didn't realize hibernate doesn't delete field from DB table. any time i make field changes i should go and change them in DB ?

Comment: @james, it depends. You can let Play! manages DB updates (`jpa.ddl` property in `application.conf`). See here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/configuration#jpa.ddl

Comment: thank you ! this would save a lot of time while studying the framework and playing around.

Answer (score 1):

Well looking into your POJO class that you have not stetted you Admin property so

Hibernate can not find the admin root where it can add the values. example is follows.

```
 @javax.persistence.Entity
    @Table(name = "Spring_Login")
    public class Table_Login implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;
}
```

and then sql Syntax wont be fail and that 
 then sql query will be the same and your Error will be solved.